Spring Method Security fails
I am trying to implement method-based security in my legacy, xml-config based  Spring 5.3 project so unfortunately I cannot use Spring Boot.
I tried two approaches, both don't work.
In both cases I am trying to make the following line of code work in my controllers:
@PreAuthorize("@mySecurity.authorize(someId)")

approach no. 1:
adding this to my security.xml:
<sec:method-security/>

<bean id="mySecurity" class="com.MySecurity"/>

throws the following Exception upon startup:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'combinedScriptResources': Error converting
typed String value for bean property 'sourceMap' with key
[TypedStringValue: value [jquery/common-combined.js], target type
[class java.lang.String]]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'java.util.LinkedList';

This makes absolutely no sense to me so I tried to achieve the same via AOP.
approach no. 2:
adding this to my security.xml:
<sec:method-security pre-post-enabled="false"/>

<aop:config/>

<bean id="preAuthorizeAuthorizationMethodInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor"
        factory-method="preAuthorize"/>

<bean id="mySecurity" class="com.MySecurity"/>

but upon calling the route in the browser I get the following error:

Failed to evaluate expression '@mySecurity.authorize('42')' EL1057E:
No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean
'mySecurity'.

So I am wondering what bean resolver I need to add and where?

Please provide your codebase via github. I can fix it quickly.

Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you.

@AnishB. Thanks for your offer but unfortunately it's a closed code base :-(

That is a lame excuse. An MCVE, if you have read the article I linked to, is a minimal reproducer. To create one from a larger code base is sometimes a bit tedious but otherwise a pretty mechanical process not requiring any special skills any software developer does not already possess. You simply strip off as much as possible from your large project bit by bit until only the minimal code reproducing your problem remains. Then, you rename module, package, class and maybe method names and publish it. There is absolutely no need to share any confidential code.
